# LDAP invalid credentials -- is the syntax correct?

Tags: ldap

I have the following simple code:

```
  $host = 'davinci-1:389';
  $base = 'dc=davinci-1,dc=mydomain,dc=local';

  $name = "cn=MYDOMAIN\Alejandro,ou=@ 2070 Logan,ou=Aquarius,$base";
  $pass = 'XXX';

  $conn = ldap_connect($host);
  $bind = ldap_bind($conn, $name, $pass);

  echo ldap_error($conn).'<br>';

  if ($bind === true) {
    echo 'Binding succeeded.';
  }
  else{
    echo 'Binding failed';    
  }
```

Fails to authenticate???

Here is my Windows AD:

```
@ 2070 Logan
  Accounting
  Aquarius
    Alejandro
    Mike 
    Justin 
  Aerospace
  Distribution
```

Is the DN correct, is that what is throwing it off?

**DN: cn=MYDOMAIN\Alejandro,ou=@ 2070 Logan,ou=Aquarius,dc=davinci-1,dc=mydomain,dc=local**

I have tried reversing the order of the OU's and everything and it doesn't work...yes I use the same credentials for logging into Windows.

Comment: I also dropped MYDOMAIN from CN as well -- still no dice :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems your DN is not correct. It should be:

```
$name = "cn=Alejandro,ou=Aquarius,ou=@ 2070 Logan,$base";
```